# Developer sandbox - Remote Signing - Not receiving email

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to prototype the code example for Requesting a Signature via Email (Remote Signing). More details can be found here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/quickstart-request-signature-email

After following the steps, the Signer does not get an email from DocuSign. I am able to verify that the order was created correctly by viewing the envelope in the DocuSign Developer Sandbox, as shown in the screenshot below:
[image: screenshot of the DocuSign Developer Sandbox view for a DocuSign envelope]

I tried to click the *Resend* button and I get a notification that the email was sent successfully, but I don't see it in my email inbox. I tried with a couple of email addresses.
[image]

I don't understand why the email is not being sent. I am able to have the Signer sign the envelope by creating a RecipientViewRequest and navigating to the URL returned by that request, but I am working on a flow that involves DocuSign sending the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a signer's emails aren't being delivered, it's likely that they're being defined as a Captive Recipient.

Check the `signer` parameters. If a `clientUserId` is defined, that user is a Captive Recipient and they will not receive an invitation to sign.

If you can provide the API log of your Envelope Creation call, I can review and confirm.

Comment: That seems to be the issue. After altering my code to not set the ClientUserId for the  Signer, then the email was successfully sent. I do notice in this case that when I create an Recipient View, then when navigating to the URL for the Recipient View I am not able to sign the envelope.

Comment: In general, email access to an envelope and Recipient View/API access to an envelope are mutually exclusive. The exception is the EmbeddedRecipientStartUrl parameter. For info on that, check out the relevant section of "https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/". Feel free to open a new question if you have issues with that.