# Need help. Prepared envelope registered but not sent to email

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am just starting to work this lib and need some help in first steps.

I need to have template for sending to defined in code recipients with prefilled data.

I have [template](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17436084/116869661-2b48f800-ac22-11eb-82b7-ba0aa00cfd88.png) with fullName field and one sign field

In code I am creating new envelope. Code example is:

```php
$envelopeDefinition = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition(
            [
                'status' => 'sent',
                'template_id' => $templateId,
            ]
        );
        $signer = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\TemplateRole(
            [
                'email' => $email,
                'name' => $name,
                'role_name' => 'signer',
                'client_user_id' => 1000,
                'tabs' => new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs(
                    [
                        'sign_here_tabs' => [
                            new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere(['tab_label' => 'sign'])
                        ]
                    ]
                )
            ]
        );
        $envelopeDefinition->setTemplateRoles([$signer]);

        $envelopeApi = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($authService->getAuthorizedApiClient());
        $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelopeDefinition);
```

Envelope was created and it is displayed in [manage tab](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17436084/116870365-83342e80-ac23-11eb-9318-730678d1722d.png) in DocusignUI

In [history](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17436084/116870258-436d4700-ac23-11eb-8589-a9fad12b6627.png) there are only register event listed. I can't see any sending invitations to email event

No email was received

Could you explain what's wrong with my code?

---

**Addition**

I am also trying to create new template in similar way as in `EG008CreateTemplate` from examples in short version to check if there are any problems with my template configuration.
My request sends post-data:

```
{
  "description": "Example template created via the API",
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentBase64": "...",
      "documentId": "1",
      "fileExtension": "pdf",
      "name": "Debug Agreement"
    }
  ],
  "emailSubject": "Please sign this document",
  "name": "Debug Agreement Template",
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "recipientId": "1",
        "roleName": "signer",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "tabs": {
          "numberTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "font": "helvetica",
              "fontSize": "size14",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "required": "false",
              "tabLabel": "numbersOnly",
              "width": "84",
              "xPosition": "163",
              "yPosition": "260"
            }
          ],
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "xPosition": "191",
              "yPosition": "148"
            }
          ],
          "textTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "font": "helvetica",
              "fontSize": "size14",
              "height": "23",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "required": "false",
              "tabLabel": "text",
              "width": "84",
              "xPosition": "153",
              "yPosition": "230"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "shared": "false",
  "status": "created"
}
```

And receives again error `The request body is missing or improperly formatted. New Account definition(s) not found in the request body.`

Who can explain what does this error means? I can't find any descriptions for this case

Comment: As I can see from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247166/developer-sandbox-remote-signing-not-receiving-email?rq=1) I should remove `client_user_id` from TemplateRole but if I made it I've received error `Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body:  O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:9:"errorCode";s:20:"INVALID_REQUEST_BODY";s:7:"message";s:109:"The request body is missing or improperly formatted. New Account definition(s) not found in the request body.";} `

Comment: I am also trying to create new template in similar way as in `EG008CreateTemplate` from examples. And receives again error `The request body is missing or improperly formatted. New Account definition(s) not found in the request body.`

Who can explain what does this error means? I can't find any descriptions for this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out this line:

```
'client_user_id' => 1000
```

This line is used for [embedded signing](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/embedding/), which is not sending an email, because you embed it in your app.
You want remote signing with an email, so you shouldn't provide a client_user_id.

Comment: But when I removed this line I've received error from Docusign: `The request body is missing or improperly formatted. New Account definition(s) not found in the request body`

Answer (score 1):

After digging up code and request process it was detected that accountId was empty and request called `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts//templates`
Provided error message is not correct as I tend to think.

It is strange for me that I was able to get templates list, create new envelopes with empty accountId...